# IntelliJ Idea - JUnit5 - Getting an error -> [ '@Suite' not applicable to method ]

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, junit5

I was setting up JUnit5 in IntelliJ IDEA but while defining @Suite annotation, I am getting an error like - > [ '@Suite' not applicable to method ]. Tried to search solution on google but couldn't get similar one. Could someone please help.

**Maven POM file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.unitTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>JUnit5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>1.8</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.target.version>1.8</maven.target.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>3.0.0-M5</maven.surefire.version>
        <junit.jupiter.version>5.0.0-M2</junit.jupiter.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-suite-engine</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.jupiter.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


</project>
```

**Error Screen**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [Suite](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/api/org.junit.platform.suite.api/org/junit/platform/suite/api/Suite.html) is targeted to [TYPE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE) which means it can only apply to
Class, interface (including annotation type), or Enum declaration not to methods.

Comment: Thanks @Karhikeyan, it works when annotated at class. Now I'm getting different errors, which I need to look. Thanks.